# Xcode 5 keeps converting storyboards from the Xcode 4 format automatically

Tags: ios, xcode, storyboard

I have a project with a client that must build in Xcode 4.  The problem is when anyone opens it with Xcode 5, the storyboards get converted to the new format.  Then you have to go and change it back (inspector-->opens in) every time you open it.  Sometimes it doesn't, it seems to be about every other time the projects is opened this way.   Is there a way to keep Xcode from doing that?

Comment: Keep in mind that starting February 1st, all new apps and app updates must support iOS 7 and Xcode 5. Keeping support for Xcode 4 is only useful for non-store apps.

Comment: Thanks, this isn't for the app store.  It's enterprise development.

Comment: Why must the client build on Xcode 4? This is possibly a bug by Apple, and you could file a bug report, but you can understand why it would get very low priority and never fixed, right?